# How to define 'client' correctly in a Cog Discord.Py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to get a join / leave command working inside of a Cog. Getting the error "NameError: name 'client' is not defined" when using the command Join. I have tried to use 'self.client' instead but I just get an error that 'self' is not defined. Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks :)

```
import os
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    #Events

    #Commands
    #Join Voice Chat
    @commands.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['Join', 'JOIN'])
    async def join(self, ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()

        await voice.disconnect()

        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
                voice = await channel.connect()
                print(f"Bot has connected to {channel}\n")

                await ctx.send(f"Connected to {channel}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a folder named `cogs` where every cog will be contained.
When you have cogs, you have to replace every `client.commands()` by 'commands.command()' and every `client` occurences by `self.client`

In your main program file, for instance, `bot.py` :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
initial_extensions = ['cogs.my_cog'] #cog.(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')

bot.run('Your token')
```

In your cog program file, for instance, `my_cog.py` :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class My_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['Join', 'JOIN'])
    async def join(self, ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(My_cog(bot))
```

Comment: Hey i think i might have worded the question a little weirdly. I already have a Cogs folder setup and the code above is from there. The trouble im having is that `client` is not defined inside of `voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` and im not sure why.

Comment: Totally normal, I forgot to replace `client.voice_clients` by `self.client.voice_clients`. In your cogs, you have to replace every `client` occurences by `self.client`. I have change my answer ;)

Comment: Ive edited my code to use `self.client.voice_clients` and now i get an error like this: AttributeError: 'music' object has no attribute 'client'. Do you know what this means?

Comment: You should edit your post with your whole code. i'd need more infos to solve your problem

Comment: Hey sorry about the slow reply. Ive updated the code to include the entire join command. hopefully this helps you. Thanks for all the help so far also btw :)

Comment: Your bot variable is nammed `bot` and not `client` so that's why you have this error. You just have to write `voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` instead of  `voice = get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)`